# Python slice how to distinguish slice arguments and default arguments (e.g., x[i:] vs. x[i:None])?

Tags: python, indexing, syntax, slice, default-arguments

Assuming `variable = None`, how to programmatically distinguish the following slicing syntax (which has the same effect)?

```
obj[variable:]
obj[variable:None]

obj[:variable]
obj[None:variable]

obj[:]
obj[::]
obj[None:None]
obj[None:None:None]
```

I am trying to customize the `__getitem__` method of my class **to [ab]use the slice syntax for advanced indexing (syntactic sugar), and want to treat different slicing syntax differently as I need a lot of syntactic sugar...** (which may be not a good practice, but just for experiments...).

```
def __getitem__(self, slice_obj):
    # slice_obj will be `slice(None, None, None)` for all 
    # `obj[variable:]`, `obj[:variable]` and `obj[:]`
```

We can see there are different slice opcodes using the `dis` library:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-SLICE+0

> SLICE+0() Implements TOS = TOS[:].
>
> SLICE+1() Implements TOS = TOS1[TOS:].
>
> SLICE+2() Implements TOS = TOS1[:TOS].
>
> SLICE+3() Implements TOS = TOS2[TOS1:TOS].

So can anyone use some introspection hacks to tell the different syntax (`inspect, dis, ast,` etc.)?

**Further question**:

How to tell the passed-in arguments and default arguments in a function? E.g.,

```
def add(x, delta=1):
    return x + delta
```

Inside `add` function, how can we tell if it is called as `add(x)` or `add(x, 1)`?

**Links**:

[Can we use a unique, different default argument for slice (other than None)?]

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/slice.html#c.PySlice_New
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html#slice_nil-spec

Any comments/workarounds/hacks are appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @chepner for pointing out. I am trying to use slice as syntactic sugar, and I need a lot of sugar for different meanings... I've updated my question to highlight that.

Comment: Abuse standard syntax with great care - make sure your API cleverness outweighs any user cognitive dissonance when your slicing/dicing betrays normal use, especially among new Pythoners who are just figuring out what slices are all about.  Also, how will your API deal with a single argument that is itself a slice object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `slice` object, it is not possible to determine what type of indexing expression was used to create it. The `slice` that is created from `a[:14]` is indistinguishable from that created by `a[None:14]` or a literal `slice(None, 14)`.

If you wanted to get a little messy (and a lot unportable), though, you could probably get somewhat reliable results by looking at the current opcode in the parent frame:

```
import sys, dis

class Moo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        parent_frame = sys._getframe().f_back
        accessing_opcode = parent_frame.f_code.co_code[parent_frame.f_lasti]
        return "This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a %s instruction" \
                % dis.opname[ord(accessing_opcode)]
```

which would give results like:

```
>>> m = Moo()
>>> m[5]
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a BINARY_SUBSCR instruction'
>>> m[5:]
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a SLICE+1 instruction'
>>> m[:5]
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a SLICE+2 instruction'
>>> m[5:5]
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a SLICE+3 instruction'
>>> m[:5:]
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a BINARY_SUBSCR instruction'
>>> m[1:5:2]
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a BINARY_SUBSCR instruction'
```

Obviously this would be less helpful if your `__getitem__` method is called explicitly, but maybe it would address your need.

Comment: You may also have issues across versions of Python.

Comment: Thanks for your method to check the opcode! It's what I was trying to check before. Sadly we still can't tell the difference from a `slice` object. As @PaulMcGuire has commented, I may have to rethink about my syntax design.

Comment: Just to add to your nice example, `m[slice_obj] -> 
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a BINARY_SUBSCR instruction'`, `m.__getitem__(slice_obj) -> 
'This __getitem__ was invoked by way of a CALL_FUNCTION instruction'`

Answer (score 0):

For the second part determining what a function is called with:

```
import inspect
>>> def add(a, b=0):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> inspect.getargspec(add)
(['a', 'b'], None, None, (0,))
>>> len(inspect.getargspec(add)[0])
2
```

Comment: Thanks, I will read more about inspect and experiment with your method.

Comment: You could also default an argument to some abstract value, check the value, if it's still abstract then set it to the correct default! This could get quite lengthy if you had several arguments!                                                  def add(a, b=6996420):
    if b == 6996420:
        b = 1
    return a+b